# How to insert one record at a time?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having some 8 text boxes and one submit button. I just want to insert only one text box value into db when I press submit. So, I must press submit button 8 times to enter all the text box values into the db.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=Sadiq;Initial Catalog=rafi;Integrated Security=True";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "student1";
int studid = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
string name = TextBox2.Text;
int age = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
string school = TextBox4.Text;
string clas = TextBox5.Text;
int marks = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text);
string grade = TextBox7.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stud_id", studid));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", name));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@age", age));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@school", school));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@class", clas));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@marks", marks));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@grade", grade));
cmd.Connection=conn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Please post your code you've tried out so far.

Comment: What does this code do, what do you want it to do and what have you tried?

Comment: this works for inserting all the text box values in single submit button click. my requirement is to insert only one text box value at one submit click. is this possible??

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Those `TextBox` values depend on each other, every one is for a different column in your table. So why and how do you want to separate it into multiple insert/updates?

Comment: @user3045190 you *are* inserting one record (aka tupel) at a time with that code.

Comment: Also without knowing what your stored procedure in Oracle is, we have no way of knowing what will happen in the database once the stored procedure is executed.  It would not surprise me at all if the stored procedure would fail if only one of the parameters was set.  (Your code and the stored procedure that you are handing control to need to be designed to work together.)